# how can i hide a table cell based on a previous cell?

Tags: jquery, azureportal

I have table cells that include (data-attribute="description") that I want to hide (or the contents within) only if the previous cell includes (data-value="email") or (aria-label="Email")

.crmEntityFormView table.table td

```
<td data-type="System.String" data-attribute="activitytypecode" data-value="email" data-th="Activity Type" aria-label="Email">Email</td>

<td data-type="System.String" data-attribute="description"> something </td>
```

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery you can use `prev` to get the previous sibling, so select all `td` elements with `data-attribute` description and iterate the collection checking each sibling for the required `data-value` and `aria-label`:

```js
$(function(){
  $('td[data-attribute="description"]').each(function(){
      const $prev = $(this).prev();
      if($prev.length && 
        ($prev.data('value') === 'email' || 
         $prev.attr("aria-label") === 'Email')){
            $(this).hide();
      }
  });
});
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-3zlB5s2uwoUzrXK3BT7AX3FyvojsraNFxCc2vC/7pNI="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<table>
<tr>
    <td data-type="System.String" data-attribute="activitytypecode" data-value="email" data-th="Activity Type" aria-label="Email">Email</td>
    <td data-type="System.String" data-attribute="description"> something </td>
</tr>
<tr>
     <td data-type="System.String" data-attribute="activitytypecode" data-value="not-email" data-th="Activity Type" aria-label="Not-Email">Not Email</td>
     <td data-type="System.String" data-attribute="description"> something </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: genius! anyway to keep it working when sorting or paginating though?

Comment: @bstime You'd need to run it after sorting, with pagination, you'd need to get the object array behind it and do a check there since you would want to exclude those items before displaying x number of rows, but that would be best suited for another post, if this answers your post, feel free to mark as accepted answer.